# Is there a concept of Free Model for any given classical first order theory?

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

Just as in the wikipedia for 'Free object' there are free groups, monoids and other algebraically flavored structures, and given a set of axioms in the language of a signature and standard predicate logic, is there a distinguised structure built with syntactic means satisfying them, and having a nice universal property akin to that of the mentioned free objects? Where would be the details?

Comment: Every finitary algebraic category has free objects; is that the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: Free objects do not exist in any reasonable sense for most first-order theories.  We see this already in some familiar algebraic examples: for instance, there is no such thing as a free field.

Comment: While freeness breaks down in the more general context of first-order theories, I think you may be interested in the various notions of "special" models: on the "canonical" side, we have [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_model) and [atomic models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_model_(mathematical_logic)), and on the "maximal" side we have [saturated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model) and [universal models](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Universal_Model). (cont'd)

Comment: *Note that these apply to complete first-order theories; incomplete theories are less well-behaved.* You'll probably also be interested in the various homogeneity notions for first-order structures. And [Fraisse limits](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/fraisse_limits.html) also provide an interesting notion of "generic" model. While simple notions like "free group" fail to generalize to arbitrary first-order theories, there are still often models which are "generic" or "canonical" in various important ways, and these play fundamental roles.

Comment: I don't think the question is entirely clear: given a first order theory, there are at least three different categories whose objects are models of that theory (depending on whether your morphisms are homomorphisms, strong homomorphisms, or elementary maps). Each of those yields a notion of a free model. But I guess that most first order theories don't have any of those. Are you asking for criteria of having free models? Which ones? Or just weaker analogues that occur more often?

Comment: My long answer doesn't fit here, but in short I'm interested in weak homomorphisms because those are what arise in algebra while embeddings or stongs are only a part. Injectivity is too restrictive and the homo from (Z, +) to the field Z_p for p prime is not strong in a relational presentation of the theory of groups, but it belong to the category I'm interested in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most general first-order context in which free models exist is the universal Horn theories. These are the theories which are axiomatized by universal Horn sentences, which have the form $$\forall \overline{x}\, \left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(\overline{x})\rightarrow \psi(\overline{x})\right),$$
where all of the formulas $\varphi_i(\overline{x})$ and $\psi(\overline{x})$ are atomic.

Note that in the case $n = 0$, the left-hand side of the implication is the empty conjunction $\top$, so the sentence is equivalent to $\forall\overline{x}\,\psi(\overline{x})$, for atomic $\psi(\overline{x})$. Thus every equational algebraic theory (groups, commutative rings, etc.) is a universal Horn theory, since they are axiomatized by universally quantified equations.

To build the free model of a universal Horn theory $T$ on generators $X$, we build up a set $\Delta$ of atomic formulas in the variables $X$, starting from the empty set, and closing under the usual rules for equality, together with the closure conditions given by the sentences axiomatizing $T$.

Explicitly,

1. Put $t = t$ in $\Delta$ for every term $t$.
2. If $s = t$ is in $\Delta$, put $t = s$ in $\Delta$.
3. If $s = t$ and $t = u$ are in $\Delta$, put $s = u$ in $\Delta$.
4. If $s_i = t_i$ is in $\Delta$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, and $R(s_1,\dots,s_k)$ is in $\Delta$ for a $k$-ary relation $R$, put $R(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ in $\Delta$.
5. For every sentence $\forall \overline{x}\, \left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(\overline{x})\rightarrow \psi(\overline{x})\right)$ in the axiomatization of $T$, if $\varphi_i(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ is in $\Delta$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, put $\psi(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ in $\Delta$.

Having obtained the minimal closed set $\Delta$, we construct the term algebra $\mathcal{T}_X$ on $X$, take the quotient $\mathcal{T}_X/\sim$ by the equivalence relation $s\sim t\iff s=t\in \Delta$, and for each $k$-ary relation symbol $R$ and tuple of equivalence classes $[s_1],\dots,[s_k]$, set $R([s_1],\dots,[s_k]) \iff R(s_1,\dots,s_k)\in \Delta$.

Extra comments:

- The classes of structures axiomatizable by universal Horn theories are exactly those elementary classes which are closed under substructure and product.
- Even for general universal theories, you immediately run into problems building free models. For example, consider the language with two predicates $P$ and $Q$, and the universal axiom $\forall x\, (P(x)\lor Q(x))$. In the "free model" on $1$ generator $a$, if $a$ satisfies $P$, it can't be mapped to an element satisfying $Q$ but not $P$. And if $a$ satisfies $Q$, it can't be mapped to an element satisfying $P$ but not $Q$. The problem is essentially with disjunction - in the free model construction for universal Horn theories, we could satisfy all the axioms without ever having to make any choices.
- In categorical logic, the [essentially algebraic theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+algebraic+theory) are a slight generalization of first-order universal Horn theories in languages without relation symbols.
- In the comments, Noah mentions some other kinds of models in first-order model theory which are canonical in certain senses. I love all of these kinds of models dearly, but I wanted to give a few caveats to these notions: prime and atomic models only exist for certain theories (in a countable language, it's those in which the isolated types are dense in the types spaces over $\emptyset$), saturated models are only canonical (in the sense that they're unique up to isomorphism) in a fixed cardinality, and in general you need set theoretic hypotheses (or stability) for them to exist, and universal models are not even unique up to isomorphism.
- *Most important caveat:* In the category of models of a general first-order theory, you shouldn't expect to find objects satisfying universal properties in the usual sense. Universal properties assert uniqueness of arrows, and that's extremely uncommon in the elementary context. For example, a prime model of $T$ is one which embeds elementarily into every model of $T$, but this elementary embedding is typically *not* unique (so a prime model is *not* an initial object in the category of models of $T$ and elementary embeddings). The prime model of the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, which admits lots of elementary embeddings into any model of ACF$_0$ (pick any such embedding, and then precompose with any automorphism in $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. Similarly, saturated models of size $\kappa$ are unique up to isomorphism, but not unique up to *unique* isomorphism.